# XMLSerialiser without &amp;

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I'm using XMLSerializer to serialize a DOM however it's converting all `&` into `&amp;` and `>` into `$lt;` etc.

Is there anyway to stop this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't do this no.

The `XMLSerializer` takes a DOM node and serialize it to an XHTML markup.

In the DOM, your `<` or `&` characters you may have in the original markup have **already** been converted to their HTML entities equivalent.

```js
console.log(test.innerHTML); //&amp;
```

```html
<span id="test">&</span>
```

So when you serialize these DOM elements using the XMLSerializer, it will correctly extract it as HTML entities in the output markup.

*i.e* there is no way to stop this behavior, since there is no such behavior to begin with.